# How to join and 'multiply' two lists?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following lists

```
A = {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 0, 3}};
B = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}};
```

and I don't know how to join them to create a list `C` in the following way:

```
C = {{1, 2, 3, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
     {1, 0, 3, 1, 2}, {1, 0, 3, 3, 4}, {1, 0, 3, 4, 5}}
```

That is, I want to join then as by `Join[]` but also 'multiply'.

My second question is how to do the same operation on `A` and `B` conditioned on the value of `A[[;; , 2]]`. Say, combine them as described only for `A[[1 , 2]]=2` and ignore otherwise without relying on a loop.

Comment: Your second question is unclear to me, what output do you expect?

Comment: I expect just this C = {{1, 2, 3, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}} because the second value of the second 'row' of A is not 2.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remember`Outer` everytime you try to do something you call as 'multiply'.

```
Outer[Join, A, B, 1]
```

> {{{1, 2, 3, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}, {{1, 0, 3, 1, 2}, {1, 0, 3, 3, 4}, {1, 0, 3, 4, 5}}}

`Join` as the function, and `A` and `B` as two vectors, then do `Outer` at level 1 shall give you a proper result.

I don't know what you want for the second part of your question, but I suppose adding a filter directly to `A` will do the job:

```
Select[A,#[[2]]!=2&]
```

Comment: That is what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

This appears to be 7-10 times faster than `Outer`, depending of lists length:

```
 With[{l = Length[B]},
   Function[
      subA, Join[ConstantArray[subA, l], B, 2]
   ] /@ A
 ]
```

Comment: This solution is **CONSIDERABLY** faster than mine when `A` and `B` are huge, but not that fast when `A` and `B` are the simple situation OP posted. May I ask why this method will be faster in most cases? is this because of the reduced calls of `Join`?

Comment: @Wjx I'm not an expert in performance tunning but notice that we are Joining here row by row instead of each pair. Also, Map autocompiles for larger lists (which I don't know if happens here).

Comment: oh, maybe that's the case, thanks for your explanation!

Comment: If I could accept two post I would do it here too because in reality my lists are huge.

Comment: Then you really should accept @Kuba's answer. I mean, his answer is better than mine for you, and I won't mind that 15 rep.

Comment: But you were first and I did not specify that my lists are big so...

Comment: @dzaohpeq and Wjx, doesn't matter :-)

Answer (score 6):

```
Join @@@ Tuples[{A, B}]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 0, 3, 1, 2}, {1, 0, 3, 3, 4}, {1, 0, 3, 4, 5}}

or

```
Distribute[{A, B}, List, List, List, Join]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 0, 3, 1,  2}, {1, 0, 3, 3, 4}, {1, 0, 3, 4, 5}}

Answer (score 5):

I know the best approach for your case is using `Outer[]` directly. Here is another method:

```
Table[Join[A[[i]], B[[j]]], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 3}] // Flatten[#, 1] &

(*{{1, 2, 3, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 
   {1, 0, 3, 1, 2}, {1, 0, 3, 3, 4}, {1, 0, 3, 4, 5}}*)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
A = {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 0, 3}}
B = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}

Table[Join[A[[l]], B[[n]]], {l, 1, 2, 1}, {n, 1, 3, 1}]
```

Comment: how did you make the gray rectangle Wjx?

Comment: Highlight (drag) your code, and press the `{}` button

Comment: ah thanks, i did not know

Comment: Also, if you want to @ someone, you should use @Wjx instead of directly typing it. I won't be mentioned if you directly type Wjx. :)