# concatenate a list with itself

Tags: list-manipulation

I guess this is rather trivial. Given, e.g.,

```
L={1,2}
```

what are some common efficient ways to obtain

```
L
(*{1,2,1,2,1,2}*)
```

that is, the list concatenated three times with itself and obtained the new value. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Catenate@ConstantArray[L, 3]`?

Comment: closely related: [**111863**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/111863/5478), [**113327**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/113327/5478) related: [**123743**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/123743/5478)

Comment: Outer[Times, ConstantArray[1, 5], {1, 2}] // Flatten

Comment: This makes me think there is a duplicate somewhere `ArrayPad[{1, 2}, 2, "Periodic"]`

Comment: Is this close enough for a duplicate? [**Generate cyclic list from a list**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76246/5478)

Comment: Thanks for the comments and suggested workarounds. I accept the duplicate nature of the question but just as a side remark. I wrote: ""I guess this is rather trivial". After having seen the responses I think I should not have written this phrase. I use Mathematica for several years and still I could not find anything to do it on my oown. I use Python for one month and I am able to simply write `3*L` to get the desired output:-)!

Comment: Maybe just because you encounter two "non-normal" answers.So you will think this.:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
L = {1, 2};
Charting`padList[L, 6]
```

> {1,2,1,2,1,2}

---

Ps:Function `` Charting`CommonDump`listPad ``,`Catenate`,`Flatten`,`ReplicateLayer`,`PaddingLayer`,`Table`,`ConstantArray`,`ArrayReshape` and `Array` is relevant.Also `ArrayPad` from [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba)'s comment [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141831/concatenate-a-list-with-itself/141833#comment383320_141831).

Answer (score 4):

There is a dedicated function in R:

```
Needs["RLink`"]    
InstallR[]    
REvaluate["rep(c(1,2),5)"]

(* {1., 2., 1., 2., 1., 2., 1., 2., 1., 2.} *)
```

Another possibility is to use `length.out`:

```
REvaluate["rep(c(1,2),length.out=5)"]    

(* {1., 2., 1., 2., 1.} *)
```

Comment: Upvote for trick..

Comment: @yode It is related to your answer, using a dedicated function.